# Continuous calls of onBindViewHolder() if animation added in item view

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which has animation added for each item in onBindViewHolder() which results in multiple calls for single item in recycler view.

My requirement is to zoom in image on selection of an item in recycler-view. I have started an animation in onBindViewHolder() for each item which has resulted in continuous calls of onBindViewHolder() for same item.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder viewHolder, int viewType) {
    viewHolder.imageView.animate().scaleX(scaleX).scaleY(scaleY).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            viewHolder.imageView.animate().setListener(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).setDuration(THUMBNAIL_ZOOMING_DURATION).start();
}
```

Imageview should zoom in by 1.15f when an item gets selected with animation and should get zoom out if deselected.

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` is not a good place for animations. Try using [`onViewAttachedToWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onviewattachedtowindow) to start and `onViewDetachedFromWindow` to stop animations

Comment: onViewAttachedToWindow() and onViewDetachedFromWindow() will not fulfill my requirement of zooming in on selection and zooming out on deselection.

Just to let you know, I tried your solution. It works fine with selection of item as view is attached again on selection but does not works in second part, i.e. zooming out on deselection.